# Bibliography wont append to main

Tags: biblatex, pdftex

I'm having trouble getting the bibliography to show up in the following example:

main.tex:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

Hi \cite{bib:markramEqns}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

references.bib:

```latex
@article{bib:markramEqns,
    author        = {M Tsodyks, K Pawelzik, and H Markram},
    title         = {Neural networks with dynamic synapses},
    journaltitle  = {Neural computation},
    year          = {1998},
    volume        = {10},
    number        = {4},
    pages         = {821-835}
}
```

Compiler complaints:

```
No file main.bbl.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'bib:markramEqns' on page 1 undefined on input line 8.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 10.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

What is going on?

Comment: Did you run biber? Other than that, the code works without problems for me

Comment: well that might be the problem, what's biber?

Comment: biber is the program which generates the bibliography. Which editor do you use? How do you compile your document?

Comment: editor: TeXworks. compiler: pdfLatex

Comment: check if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations can help

Comment: I also have a work flow where I do this in terminal. there do I run pdflatex main.tex, biber main.tex, pdflatex main.tex? this doesnt appear to work for me

Comment: Don't use the file endings: `pdflatex main, biber main, pdflatex main`

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864

Comment: Any news here? Do things work now? Would you say the question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864?

Comment: @moewe my discussion with Pizzagne solved my problems! You link to the post explaining what biblatex is was useful for me as well!